# selenium with python action chains not working

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I am trying to send a ALT+ESC command to my selenium chrome-driver to send it to the back of all other windows

This is the relevant code

```
from selenium.webdriver import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.send_keys(Keys.LEFT_ALT, Keys.ESCAPE)
actions.perform()
```

this is not working please help

Comment: Does any of our solutions resolve your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ultimately I couldn't find a way to execute a OS command in selenium.

The following code has the same functionality but dose not necessarily run on the browser

```
from pyautogui import hotkey
hotkey('altleft', 'esc')
```

Answer (score 1):

To press key-combo:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.LEFT_ALT).send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE).key_up(Keys.LEFT_ALT).perform()
```

But seems this is an OS-level keys combination for work with windows and this will not work in the selenium context.

Selenium actions applied to web page elements, fire some events inside browser.

Comment: is there any way to send OS level commands within selenium

Comment: @PythonPro I see, you've found the answer. Yes OS gui automation tool, but I less experienced..